# The number of $q$-Sylow subgroups cannot be $p$ for prime $p<q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Since $q>p $,  we cannot have $n_q=p $.

Here $n_q $ is the number of $q $ Sylow subgroups.

Why is the above statement true? This is a statement from Dummit and Foote.

Answer (score 1):

Third Sylow theorem says that $q|(n_q-1)$, thats why.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the Sylow theorems is that $n_q\equiv 1\bmod q$, so that $n_q$ must be in
$$\{1,\,1+q,\,1+2q,\,\ldots\}$$
But $p$ is strictly between $1$ and $1+q$ (because it's been assumed that $q>p$, and $p$ is a prime so it's bigger than $1$), so it's impossible for $p$ to be in this set of possible values.